# How do I center this navbar with links and dropdown items?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm trying to figure out how to center this navbar that contains links and dropdown items. I'm able to get the links centered by themselves and the dropdown items centered by themselves but when attempting to get them all centered together they appear centered horizontally but not vertically. Currently they look like this [left aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzVLc.jpg). When i change the floats to none (and add flex as suggested) i get this one [improperly centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W756B.jpg).

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: #666666;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  padding: 14px 16px;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#">a</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">b</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">1</a>
      <a href="#">2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">c</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">3</a>
      <a href="#">4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#">d</a>
</div>
```

Comment: can u add a screenshot of what your seeing and what your trying to accomplish?  I see them vertically centered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex for that matter...

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: #666666;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  padding: 14px 16px;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#">a</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">b</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">1</a>
      <a href="#">2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">c</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">3</a>
      <a href="#">4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#">d</a>
</div>
```